# permission errors in drupal setup

Tags: drupal

Im attempting to install Drupal 7 on a VM (CentOS 6.4 x64). I have copied all the files from the tar.gz to /var/www/html (after installing Apache ). I managed to solve most of the PHP issues but it's still complaining about some permissions problems.

Specifically:

```
The directory sites/default/files is not writable. An automated attempt to create 
   this directory failed, possibly due to a permissions problem.
```

I set the whole Drupal install to `chown -R apache:apache` and the path in question is set via `chmod -R oug+rw sites`.

It's also complaining about:

```
The Drupal installer requires write permissions to ./sites/default/settings.php 
   during the installation process.
```

The file is set to 666 and the path is wide open.

Clearly I'm missing something obvious here. Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure PHP is running as apache?  It might not be if you are using suphp, or several other methods to launch php.

Comment: I installed it using `yum install php`. I don't see any account(s) for it in \etc\passwd. Somewhere else to check?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it's SELinux being helpful.

To fix:

```
setenforce 0
do the installation
setenforce 1
```